# WSO2 ESB using computer name for axis services

Tags: ssl, wso2, apache-axis, wso2-esb

When I deploy an axis service on WSO2 ESB, the endpoint URL for the axis service contains my hostname.  How would I change this to an IP address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change to your IP address you must edit the axis2.xml in /repository/conf/axis2

```
<!--parameter name="WSDLEPRPrefix" locked="false">https://apachehost:port/somepath</parameter-->
```

to `<parameter name="WSDLEPRPrefix" locked="false">https://10.100.4.10:8280/</parameter>` for both http and https tranport listeners.

Comment: Thanks, it works.  But, why is it not working if I change bind-address, any ideas?